# MySQL UPDATE with INNER JOIN has warnings but will not show them

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I'm getting warnings when updating a table but the warnings are not showing. Through tedious and lengthy trial-and-error, the cause of the warnings has been tracked down to the INNER JOIN. I need a better way to debug a warning.

Setup is OK. I know warnings are on because MySQL command prompt was started with option '--show-warnings' and warnings are turned on warnings with '\W':

```
mysql> \W
Show warnings enabled.

mysql> show variables like '%warn%';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_warnings  | 0     |
| sql_warnings  | ON    |
| warning_count | 0     |
+---------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

To make sure warnings were on, I forced a truncating warning on a VARCHAR(255) field:

```
mysql> UPDATE course
    -> SET course.transcript_title = 'Field transcript_title is VARCHAR(255). This is over 255 characters to force truncating warning. Field transcript_title is VARCHAR(255). This is over 255 characters to force truncating warning. Field transcript_title is VARCHAR(255). This is over 255 characters to force truncating warning.'
    -> WHERE course.title LIKE '%SLP%'
    -> AND course.year = 2008
    -> AND course.gid = 35;
Query OK, 104 rows affected, 104 warnings (0.19 sec)
Rows matched: 104  Changed: 104  Warnings: 104

Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'transcript_title' at row 1
Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'transcript_title' at row 2
.... etc.
```

I want to get the warning from this type of query:

```
mysql> UPDATE course
    -> INNER JOIN group_info ON course.gid = group_info.id
    -> SET course.description = 'Foo.'
    -> WHERE course.title LIKE '%SLP%'
    -> AND course.year = 2008 AND group_info.id = 35;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 104  Changed: 0  Warnings: 104

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

From trial and error, I know the error is from having the INNER JOIN clause. If I remove the INNER JOIN and directly use the gid (group id) field in the course table, then no warnings:

```
mysql> UPDATE course
    -> SET course.description = 'Bar.'
    -> WHERE course.title LIKE '%SLP%'
    -> AND course.year = 2008
    -> AND course.gid = 35;
Query OK, 104 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 104  Changed: 104  Warnings: 0
```

But I need the INNER JOIN clause because what I really want to do is use the more friendly 'name' field in the joined 'group_info' table:

```
UPDATE course
INNER JOIN group_info ON course.gid = group_info.id
SET course.description = 'Foo.'
WHERE course.title LIKE '%SLP%'
AND course.year = 2008
AND group_info.name = 'One-to-One Meeting Time';
```

I've been googling, reading, and debugging the warning for over 1 hour. I've searched for answers or explanations for why this would not show warnings but no luck.

How do I get warnings to show for the INNER JOIN type of UPDATE?

Comment: does the same thing happen if you use LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, Yes. Same amount of warnings for LEFT JOIN. Using RIGHT JOIN also gives same amount of warnings. I know the warning is related to the JOIN. It would be nice if the warning would pop-up to give a hint of why.